# Remove leading and trailing characters from a

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I have a text file which has strings separated by whitespace. The text file contains some special characters (latin, currency, punctuations etc.) Which need to be discarded from final output. Please note that legal characters are all characters in Unicode except these special characters.

We need to separate/split text by whitespaces and then remove only leading and trailing special characters. If special characters are in between two legal characters then we won't remove them.

I can easily do it in two phases. Split text by whitespaces and then remove only leading and trailing special characters from each string. However, I need to process string only once. Is there any way, it could be achieved in one pass. Note: We can't use RegEx.
For this question assume that these characters are special:

```
[: , ! . < ; '  "  >  [ ] { }  `  ~ = + - ? / ]
```

Example:

```
:!/,.<;:.?;,BBM!/,.<;:.?;,` IS TALKING TO `B!?AM!/,.<;:.?;,
```

Here output would be an array of valid strings: `["BBM", "IS", "TALKING", "TO", "B!?AM"]`

Comment: Can you please edit your last sentence? Is that one string in the example? Maybe you can try to format it as a code example, use 4 spaces indentation or backticks "`".

Comment: What's wrong with " IS TALKING TO" and "!/,.<;:.?;, " after the first word? Specify what should be removed more clear.

Comment: Those are special characters. For now, consider these characters as special [: , ! . < ; '  "  >  [ ] { }  `  ~ = + - ? / ]

Comment: Why !? are legal in B!?AM and not legal after BBM?

Comment: As question says, we need to remove only leading and trailing special characters.
If these special characters comes in between two legal characters , we should not remove them

Comment: What's the reason behind the constraints? Why not using RegEx and why must it be in one pass? What does mean one pass here in this context?

Comment: You can write a simple `for` loop?

Comment: To use regex, it will be complicated, because there are more than 50 special characters, also it is an interview question so constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used typescript and have done it in a single pass.
Please note that isSpecialCharacterCode(charCode) function simply checks whether unicode of text character is same as unicode of provided special characters.Same is true for isWhitespaceCode(charCode) function.

```js
  

parseText(text: string): string[]{

    let words : string[] = [];
    let word = "";
    let charCode = 1;

    let haveSeenLegalChar = false; //set it if we have encountered legal character in text

    let seenSpecialCharsToInclude = false; //set it if we have encountered //special character in text

    let inBetweenSpecialChars = ""; // string containing special chars //which may be included in between legal word

    for(let index = 0; index < text.length; index++){

        charCode = text.charCodeAt(index);
        let isSpecialChar = isSpecialCharacterCode(charCode);
        let isWhitespace = isWhitespaceCode(charCode);
        if(isSpecialChar && !isWhitespace){
            //if this is a special character then two cases
            //first is: It can be part of word (it is only possible if we have already seen atleast one legal character)
            //Since it can be part of word but we are not sure whether this will be part of word so store it for now
            //second is: This is either leading or trailing special character..we should not include these in word
            if(haveSeenLegalChar){
                inBetweenSpecialChars += text[index];
                seenSpecialCharsToInclude = true;
            }else{
                //since we have not seen any legal character till now so it must be either leading or trailing special chars
                seenSpecialCharsToInclude = false;
                inBetweenSpecialChars = "";
            }
        }else if(isWhitespace){
            //we have encountered a whitespace.This is either beginning of word or ending of word.
            //if we have encountered any leagl char, push word into array
            if(haveSeenLegalChar){
                words.push(word);
                word = "";
                inBetweenSpecialChars = "";
            }
            haveSeenLegalChar = false;
        }else if(!isSpecialChar){
            //legal character case
            haveSeenLegalChar = true;
            if(seenSpecialCharsToInclude){
                word += inBetweenSpecialChars;
                seenSpecialCharsToInclude = false;
                inBetweenSpecialChars = "";
            }
            word += text[index];
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make simple state machine (finite automata)
- Walk in a loop through all chars
- At every step check if current char is letter, space or special
- Execute some operation (perhaps empty) depending on state and char kind
- Change state if needed

for example, you may stay in "special" state until letter is met. Remember starting index of the word and make state "inside word". Continue until special char or space is met (it is still not clear from your question).